# Redis in Django: redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to 127.0.0.1:20789:0. Name or service not known

Tags: python, django, redis

I'm using django-cache-redis, and I'm stuck in the following paradox:

```
# in `python manage.py shell`
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='127.0.0.1', port=20789, db=0)
r.set('foo', 'bar')  # returns True

from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('foo', 'bar', 1)  # raises redis.exceptions.ConnectionError
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to 127.0.0.1:20789:0. Name or service not known.

Notice that the host, the port and the db are the same in both cases.

The use of `import redis` was already a debug; using redis-ctl also works. I also tried changing from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25175919/931303), without success.

Any idea of what this might be?

My `CACHES` config is already the minimal one:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:20789:0',
        'TIMEOUT': 60*60*24,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing, but you have:

```
'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:20789:0'
```

Whereas readme for django-redis-cache specifies:

```
'LOCATION': '<host>:<port>'
```

i.e. without the `:<db>` on the end

https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache

Comment: Crap. I took the notation from Django-Celery: `BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:20789/0'` by mistake. Thanks!